# Navigation Drawer setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want the navigation drawer to show up wenn clicking a button, therefore I use the following code. I handle click events inside the custom adapter, but the drawer does not close at any point in time when clicking any of the objects in my list. Any idea how to fix that?
Another problem is that I can draw in the navigation drawer only from the bottom to the middle of the screen. How can I fix that?
In my Activity

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
        }
    });


    String[] values = new String[] { "1:","2","","3"};
    MySimpleArrayAdapterUhr adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapterUhr(this, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // Closing the drawer
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

        }
    });
```

My Adapter:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] names;

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;
    public LinearLayout full;
}

public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Activity context, String[] names) {
    super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_item, names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        // configure view holder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.full = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.full);
        viewHolder.text = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    // fill data
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    String s = names[position];
    holder.text.setText(s);
    if (s.equals("1")) {
        holder.text.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        v.invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        v.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity_einstellungen_ereignis_erstellen.class);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                        Button view = (Button) v;
                        view.invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return true;
        });
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

}

Comment: You figure it out, I have the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code
declare variable as   private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); 
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); 
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } else { 
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } 
        } 
    }); 


    String[] values = new String[] { "1:","2","","3"}; 
    MySimpleArrayAdapterUhr adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapterUhr(this, values); 
    setListAdapter(adapter); 

// enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        } <br>
```

fellow this links [click here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)